# Retrieving multiple objects based on one attribute Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JSON so I am not even sure if it's possible to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Is it possible to get multiple objects based on one attribute?
Sorry if this sounds confusing.
Basically, when searching for "red" in the following code, I want it to return ALL of the objects with "red" in them. At this point, it only returns one.

```
var colors = {
    "black": {"url": "asdf","tags": "tie"},
    "red": {"url": "qwer","tags": "shirt"},
    "red": {"url": "lkj","tags": "blazer"},
    "grey": {"url": "mnvb","tags": "pants"}

}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (JSON.stringify(colors["red"]));
```

Here's a link to see how it works in its current state:
http://jsfiddle.net/8aqweLhv/

Is it possible to do this and if so, how?

Comment: you cannot have multiple object on the same Key in your case only the last red counts the one before it get overridden. what you can do make colors an array of objects. and filter/search by key

Comment: @NetaMeta What if it was one of the inner attributes? Is it possible to get all elements with one common attribute?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: Look at what mister six fingered man answered that might be what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to associate multiple values with one key, you'll need a nested structure. An Array would work.

```
var colors = {
    "black": {"url": "asdf","tags": "tie"},
    "red": [
        {"url": "qwer","tags": "shirt"},
        {"url": "lkj","tags": "blazer"}
    ],
    "grey": {"url": "mnvb","tags": "pants"}
};
```

So now `colors.red` will give you the Array, which you can iterate like normal.

```
colors.red.forEach(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.url, obj,tags);
});
```

*(By the way, that isn't JSON. It's just JavaScript's object initializer syntax, which looks strikingly similar to the JSON data interchange format)*

Comment: That would work, but then this line of code would no longer work: "document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (JSON.stringify(colors["red"])); "What could I replace it with?

Comment: @PoeticalScientist: You mean the `stringify()`? Why not?

Comment: It's just JavaScript's object initializer syntax? do you mean object literal ?

Comment: @NetaMeta: What's the difference?

Comment: The difference is "JavaScript's object initializer syntax" is not a thing

Comment: @NetaMeta: The ECMAScript specification disagrees with you: http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5

Comment: Ah, I see. I had an extra curly bracket (silly me!). Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the intent is to search on an *attribute*, not a unique key, I think what the OP is looking for is:

```
var clothing_pieces = { 
     tie: { color: "red", url: "..." },
     pants: { color: "black", url: "..." },
     shoes: { color: "red", url: "..." }
};

function getByColor(pieces, color) {
    var matchingPieces = [];
    for (p in pieces) {
        if ( pieces[p].color == color ) { matchingPieces.push(p); }
    }
    return matchingPieces
}

var myPieces = getByColor(clothing_pieces, "red");
```

The JavaScript built-in dictionary type is not powerful enough to perform the search you want with the built-in operator [].  `getByColor` can also be generalized, and is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That actually would probably work for what I'm trying to do too. I'll try it out and may end up using this instead.